# React sort data in tbody on click th in table

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to sort my data by th titles. Let's I have a const like this.

```
const headTitles = ["number", "champion", "mastery_level", "points", "progress", "tokens", "vision_score", "chest", "last_played"];
```

And I am doing this in thead:

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    {headTitles.map(title => <th key={title}><Translate use={`connekt_champions_table_${title}_title`} /></th>)}
  </tr>
</thead>
```

And then in tbody I have basic stuff like:

```
{data.map((item, i) => (
  <tr key={item.name}><td>{item.name}</td></tr>
}
```

Comment: What's the issue ?

Comment: probably `connekt_champions_table_${title}_title` should be just `connekt_champions_table_${title}`

Comment: There's no issue @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut, I just want to know how can i sort my data from these titles.

Comment: @KrešimirGalić, you want to sort the headTitles  array ?

Comment: No, that array is only to render thead values, I want to make onClick that th in thead to sort my data in tbody. Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ant design https://ant.design/components/table/ , it has several propertíes to sort data from table, or you can base on it to do it.

```
    <thead>
      <tr>
        {headTitles.map(title => <th onClick={() => sortData(title)}
         key={title}><Translate use={`connekt_champions_table_${title}_title`} /></th>)}
      </tr>
    </thead>
```

and with the variable sort the data:

```
sortData = (sortRow) => {
  const newDataSorted = data.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a[sortRow] > b[sortRow]) {
      return 1;
    }
    if (a[sortRow] < b[sortRow]) {
      return -1;
    }
    // a must be equal to b
    return 0;
  })
}
```

More info about sort in [MDN Sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/sort)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I want to do it custom, I don't want to use any plugin